# Set up Kubernetes Ingress Nginx in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

set up a kubernetes cluster locally and make kubernetes-ingress-nginx works correctly.

Now I would like to deploy it on AWS. I set up the kubernetes cluster using kubeadm and it's working correctly.

The issue now is that I can't make the ingress work. I deployed kubernetes ingress nginx.

I went through some tutorial but first most of them are based on kubernetes deployed from AWS EKS secondly some others tutorials are saying to deploy a yaml file that will automatically create a AWS Network Load Balancer but I tried to follow some but none works.

As I have a cluster of 3 nodes (1 master + 2 workers) I created a AWS Target Group for the port 80 hoping to listen at ingress controller (load balancer) deployed but none of the nodes were detected by the target group. I had hoped that from the AWS NLB I could make the ingress works.

Can someone help me with a step by step process that I can't apply to make ingress work, please ?